# Resize image on the fly in .net and c#

Tags: c#, .net, image, stream, image-resizing

I'm looking for a way to resize images without saving them on the server. The ways that i have found includes a controller file and such.

Is there a way to get the image from the stream, resize it and add it to the response?

Comment: Couple examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195064/fastest-image-resizing-in-net

Comment: This is VERY BAD IDEA! If you will get a lot of images at the one, you will get out of memory exception! Because your images will store in memory.

Comment: Maris, this is only experimental so the memory isn't really an issue. But i hope others will see this comment.

Comment: Your memory usage will be the same when done correctly either way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net) - it's a suite of NuGet packages designed for this exact purpose.

It runs eBay in Denmark, MSN Olympics, and a few other big sites.

Dynamic image processing can be done safely and efficiently, but not in a sane amount of code. It's [trickier than it appears](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend this but you can do next thing:

```
using (Image img = Image.FromStream(originalImage))
{
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(img, width, height))
    {
        bitmap.Save(outputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Be aware that this could cause OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: What is that Bitmap class

Comment: @KamranShahid, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx

Comment: Why is it when I write the `outputStream` (containing the resized image) the result is blank?  If I were to write `originalImage` to the response content the image shows...